# CSS: two column layout with each column a different color - need fluid height

Tags: css, layout, height, percentage

So, I have a two column layout and can't seem to get the height to work like I want. These both have content that needs to grow and cause the page to be scrollable - so fixed and absolute values are out. However, when using relative on these columns (and their containing div) and min-height percentages (i.e. minimum of 100% so it always at least fills screen if no content present). However, it isn't working. The min-height isn't getting recognized and I get no height unless there is content.

I realize I could have a div that's in a fixed position and solely for background. However, because sometimes within the same page (tabs) the column layout could change, I would rather not use this approach.

Anywhere here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hpAbc/80/

And some sample code from the fiddle:

```
     html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}

#container {
     width:100%;
     min-height:100%;
     padding-top:40px;
     position:relative;
 }

#nav {
     background:#222222;
     width:500px;
     height:40px;
     position:fixed;
         top:0;
    z-index:100;
}

  #content{
     background:#aaaaaa;
     width:500px;
     height:100%;
     position:relative;
 }

#main-content{
     background:#e1e1e1;
     width:300px;
     height:100%;
     float:left;
}

 #side-bar{
         background:#d1d1d1;
         width:200px;
         height:100%;
         float:left;
    }

.stuff{
         background:yellow;
         margin:10px;     
         width:50px;
         height:50px;
         position:relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use "display:table-row" and "display:table-cell" using your existing markup to get the effect you are looking for.

```
#content{
     background:#aaaaaa;
     width:500px;
     height:100%;
     position:relative;
     display:table-row; 
 }

 #main-content{
     background:#e1e1e1;
     width:300px;
     height:100%;
     display:table-cell;
 }

 #side-bar{
     background:#d1d1d1;
     width:200px;
     height:100%;
     vertical-align:top;
     display:table-cell;
 }
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PQPrW/

Alternately, if you are willing to change your markup, you can use nested divs to get the same effect. There is an article that explains it here:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks